# jQuery Mouseenter event is not firing it is firing when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-collision

jQuery mouseenter event is not firing in mouse enter it is firing when click

```
function showOverlap() {
    var hits = $('.follower').collision('#slides li');
    $(hits).trigger('mouseenter');
}

$('.container1').mouseenter(function() {
    showOverlap();
});

$('#slides li').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('#slides li').removeClass('selectedMenu');
    $(this).addClass('selectedMenu');
});
```

JsBin http://jsbin.com/urEpESAM/19/edit

here working fine if write mouseenter event  in mouseMove but it getting much  slower

Comment: What is your question here? Your subject notes a `click` event handler but I don't see one...

Comment: mouseenter event is firing on click instead of mouseenter

Comment: Guidance on writing better questions:  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('#slides li').removeClass('selectedMenu');
        $(this).addClass('selectedMenu');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       // Do stuff when mouse leaves `#slides li`
    }
}, "#slides li");
```

Comment: it is working but it too slower

Comment: Thanks your code is working fine :-)

Comment: in some situation i want stop this functionality  how to add off event for this

Answer (score 0):

if you want to trigger mouseenter event you need to bind that event. Your problem is not mouseenter.

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/stryd3r/mA3wy/

Your problem is at line:  `$(hits).trigger('mouseenter');`

Comment: Jsfiddle link is empty

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stryd3r/mA3wy/ sorry

Comment: i want using call remotley my requirement http://jsbin.com/urEpESAM/19/edit

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 function showOverlap() {
    var hits = $('.follower').collision('#slides li');
    $(hits).trigger('mouseenter');
}

$('.container1').mouseenter(function() {
    showOverlap();
});

$(this).bind('mouseenter',function(){
    alert("in");
    $('#slides li').removeClass('selectedMenu');
    $(this).addClass('selectedMenu');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stryd3r/G8FkL/)